# How to turn python dict into Curl

Tags: python

For some reasons my requests to an API is failing. This is the code:

```
def create_alert(alert_dict)
    url =  host + '/api/alerts'


    headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer tokengen'
    }
    response = requests.request('POST', url, headers = headers, data=json.dumps(alert_dict))
    return response


alert_dict = {
    "priority": "1",
    "to": to,
    "from":  from_
}


response = create_alert(alert_dict)
print(response)
```

The way I'm doing it is saving everything to a dictionary, then making the POST request with it. But for some reason im getting a 500 error.

This is the curl that is working

```
curl --location --request POST "http://newhost.com/api/alerts" \
  --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer tokengen" \
  --data "{

    \"to\": \"sample@email.com\",
    \"from\": \"from@email.com\",
    \"priority\": \"1\",

}"
```

How should I convert my dict in a way that it would work just like the curl `--data` when requested

Comment: A few things stand out: you don't provide a value for `host`, is it correct? Same for `to` and `from_`. In your curl example, the order of the three fields is different from what you show in the Python code. Can you please update your example code to have the actual values that cause the problem for those variables and confirm that the problem also occurs once you've fixed the order?

Comment: You don't need the \" if your --data is '{.  You can have a standard json if you don't use the same quotes inside and outside

Comment: what happens when you use `json` rather than `data` like `response = requests.request('POST', url, headers = headers, json=alert_dict)` ? for more info [w3schools requests](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp)

Comment: I see, I'm getting a 500 response for some reason when im requesting. But the curl does work